# Add tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tags

My markup looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="mystyle">List Item 1</span></li>
    <li><span class="mystyle">List Item 2</span></li>
    <li><span class="mystyle">List Item 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="mystyle"><a href="#">List Item 1</a></span></li>
    <li><span class="mystyle"><a href="#">List Item 2</a></span></li>
    <li><span class="mystyle"><a href="#">List Item 3</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, how can I add an HTML tag to all elements with the "mystyle" class?

Comment: 1. Select all `span`s. 2. Get their `text()` 3. Create `a` 4. Using `.html()` replace `span` contents

Comment: It almost seems like you haven't read the jQuery tutorial (or maybe you just missed that section): http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/

Comment: So many "try this" answers without proper explanation... just what we needed :-/

Comment: @Felix Kling: that's how SO works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/). Try this:

```
$('.mystyle').each(function(){
    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="#"></a>');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/b7cjL30z/)**

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have incorrect markup, you need to close span tags used. then you can use the JS:

```
$('.mystyle').each(function(){
  $(this).html('<a href="#">List Item '+$(this).html()+'</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use either [jQuery.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) --- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/yj6upeud/)

```
$('.mystyle').contents().wrap( $('<a/>',{href:'#'}) );
```

Or [jQuery.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) --- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/yj6upeud/1/)

```
$('.mystyle').wrapInner( $('<a/>',{href:'#'}) );
```

`.wrap()` - Wraps an HTML structure **around each element** in the set of matched elements.

`.wrapInner()` - Wraps an HTML structure **around the content of each element** in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 $(".mystyle").each(function () {

    $(this).html('<a href="#">' + $(this).text() + '</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$('.mystyle').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<a href="#">'+$(this).text()+'</a>');
});
```

`.html` overwrites the old html of an element with the new content, given as parameter.

Comment: post something about `.html()` function. like what it does here